# website login in using mysql and php, what's the host name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

everyone, here is the code, which I found from a youtube tutorial. I'm trying to make a login system for my website. In the second line, I should put my host name instead localhost, but i'm not sure what's my hostname. Can anyone help?? thanks!

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'rr_net_testuser', 'XXX');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'rarerock_net_test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Comment: If your database runs on the same host (server/computer) as your website, `localhost` is just fine.

Comment: Is the database located on the same server as your code base? If so see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php, specifically `It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead.` if not use the IP or domain name of the server your DB is on.. We can't tell you what this is. `stackoverflow.com` is the domain name for this site.

Comment: Maybe a good first question to ask is, do you have a MySQL database? Maybe you already know this, but that is not something that is automatically included in PHP.

Comment: Yes, I have created the database and the username password etc. But the error log keep saying access denied for user "rr_net_testuser"@"localhost"

Comment: "I found from a youtube tutorial. I'm trying to make a login system for my website." **STOP**. Please, this is how you end up in serious trouble. Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in.

Comment: There's also guides like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) which can help you navigate around serious hazards like this when learning PHP.